# How do I put these variables in place correctly?

Tags: python, variables, refactoring

```
   u = 'stringandstring'
   b = "network:"
   e = "yeser;"

   def haystack(b,e,u):
         i = re.search('%s(.*)%s', u)
         r = i.group(1)
         return r
```

or

```
  .....
  def haystack(b,e,u):
         i = re.search('b(.*)e', u)
         .....
```

how do i get those variables inside that function correctly?

Comment: y? the downvote this site is for beginners too..

Comment: thats a bad feature of this site, downvote with no explanation = no progress, only increase in ego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try concatenation (str1+str2)

```
def haystack(b,e,u):
    i = re.search(b+'(.*)'+e, u)
    if i:     #check if there is any result
        return i.group(1)    #return match

#now try to call it
print haystack("this","str","this is str")    #this should output ' is '
print haystack("no","no", "this is str")      #this should not print anything
```

this is working perfectly for me so far

Comment: Can you specify what didnt work? Only error I am getting when using concatenation with your haystack function is using `group()` even when there is no match.

Comment: im doing something silly .... >>> def hay(begin, end, astring):
...     i = re.search(begin+'(.*)'+end, astring)
... 
>>> k = hay(b,e,u)
>>> print k
None
>>>